# Accepting non-ascii characters in ASP.NET core (and JSON maybe)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, postman

I have created an API in ASP.NET Core and now I'm debugging it with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).
When I make a POST, I get an error that says:

> InvalidOperationException: Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header: 0x05D0

The application must support that language.
[Error with non-ascii input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM43e.jpg)

The code ACTUALLY WORKS, and successfully adding the entity, but yet returns this error.
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: the RFC for HTTP only allows ascii characters.  That doesn't mean you can't support any given language, but your localized text should be URL encoded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error suggests, HTTP doesn't support non-ASCII characters in the header.

Try checking your headers tab and remove any non-ASCII characters.

Comment: "HTTP doesn't support non-ASCII characters in the header" but my Java API handles them as a charm. ‍♂️